# Neo4jSession Error when trying to retrieve data from Neo4jRepository published on docker[ONLY DOCKER ISSUE]

Tags: spring-boot, docker, neo4j, docker-compose, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using docker to publish my spring-boot application with neo4j and mssql database.

I'm getting an exception *500:Internal Server Error* when I'm trying to retrieve data from  Neoj4Repository, however the exception occurs only when the application published on docker. When I'm starting spring-boot application inside Intellij Idea everything is fine. When it's published to the docker-compose Neo4jRepository  **Optional findById()** throws NullPointerException and other methods  **CollectionfindFriendsById()**  throw ArrayIndexBoundException. Furthermore when I'm trying to find my data in Neo4jBrowser  *http://localhost:7474/browser/*  - it works great. I see all data in my database, besides every query is successful. I'm attaching the code and config files. I would be very grateful if you could help me with my trouble. Please don't hesitate to give me any idea. Thanks a lot.

I've tried to use neo4j database inside docker-compose with my application instance.

**[Edited]:** As I understood spring-boot-app doesn't see *neo4j* server overall. However the app communicates with *mssql* successfully, they are both on localhost.

My 
 **docker-compose.yaml file:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  docker-neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.5.5
    ports:
    - "7474:7474"
    - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/neo4j/data:/data
      - /var/lib/neo4j/logs:/logs

  docker-current-app:
    image: current:latest
    depends_on:
    - docker-neo4j
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /usr/app/springboot-docker-compose-app
    network_mode: host
    environment:
    - JWT_SECRET=
    - JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME_MS=
```

**DockerFile for app**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY ./target/current-*.jar /usr/app/current-build.jar
WORKDIR /usr/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","current-build.jar"]
```

**application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=dbForMe
spring.datasource.username=SA
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=password
```

**Repository/service/controller**

```java
@Repository
public interface Neo4jUserRepository extends Neo4jRepository<NeoUser, Long> {

    Optional<NeoUser> findByUuid(String userId);

    @Query("MATCH (u:User {uuid : {itemId}})<-[:REQUEST]-(u2:User) RETURN u2")
    Collection<NeoUser> findRequestsById(@Param("itemId") String userId);

    @Query("MATCH (u:User {uuid:{itemId}})-[:FRIENDS]-(u2:User) RETURN u2")
    Collection<NeoUser> findFriendsById(@Param("itemId") String userId);

}

@Service
public class RelationshipsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RelationshipsService.class.getName());

    private final Neo4jUserRepository userRepository;

public RelationshipsService(Neo4jUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

 public List<UserPreview> getReceivedRequests(String userId) {
        log.info("Getting requests for itemId {}", userId);
        return userRepository.findRequestsById(userId).stream()
                .map(this::toUserPreview)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<UserPreview> getFriends(String userId) {
        log.info("Getting friends for itemId {}", userId);
        return userRepository.findFriendsById(userId).stream()
                .map(this::toUserPreview)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/relationships")
public class RelationshipController {

    private final RelationshipsService service;

    public RelationshipController(RelationshipsService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

 @GetMapping("/getFriends/{userId}")
    public List<UserPreview> getFriends(@PathVariable String userId) {
        return service.getFriends(userId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getRequests/{userId}")
    public List<UserPreview> getReceivedRequests(@PathVariable String userId) {
        return service.getReceivedRequests(userId);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>artem.bashtovyi</groupId>
    <artifactId>current</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>current</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

```
docker-current-app_1  | 2019-05-05 20:33:43.684  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.b.c.service.RelationshipsService       : Getting requests for itemId ff80818169ae57130169b0d4661f0002
docker-current-app_1  | 2019-05-05 20:33:43.965  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] Driver                                   : Direct driver instance 1518060028 created for server address localhost:7687
docker-current-app_1  | 2019-05-05 20:33:44.829  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Error executing query : 0. Rolling back transaction.
docker-current-app_1  | 2019-05-05 20:33:44.865 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0] with root cause
docker-current-app_1  | 
docker-current-app_1  | java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityRowModelMapper.extractColumnValue(EntityRowModelMapper.java:75) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityRowModelMapper.map(EntityRowModelMapper.java:64) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.lambda$executeAndMap$1(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:133) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:579) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:558) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:124) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:413) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.6.jar!/:3.1.6]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$0(SharedSessionCreator.java:108) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invokeInTransaction(SharedSessionCreator.java:139) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:110) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:96) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:57) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.findRequestsById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
docker-current-app_1  |     at com.bashtovyi.current.service.RelationshipsService.getReceivedRequests(RelationshipsService.java:40) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
docker-current-app_1  |     at com.bashtovyi.current.controller.RelationshipController.getReceivedRequests(RelationshipController.java:39) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at com.bashtovyi.current.custom.token.JwtAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthFilter.java:52) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
docker-current-app_1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It appeared that server had some old Oracle JDK. When I installed a newer OpenJDK package (change like 1.8.0_141 -> 1.8.0_222), problem disappeared.